# I just set background image in navigation controller

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller, background-image

first ,

**[ MainWindow.xib ]**

view controller set A controller (custom class)

**[A controller.xib]**

View

- imageview (a.png)
- scrollview.
        . 
        .

So, I saw a background image(a.png). and scrollview did a operate.

but. I set navi controller now .

**[MainWindow.xib]**

navigation controller

-view controller set A controller (customclass)

**[A Controller.xib]**

-View

- Image view
- Scrollw view
     .
     .
     .

can't see a background image now.

only black background is in.

I try put image view  in navigation controller .

**[MainWindow.xib]**

navigation controller

```
  -View controller set A controller(cutom class)
  -image view
```

**[A controller.xib]**

view

```
 -scroll view
```

So I can see a background image. but don't work scrollview

I would like see a background image and do work scrollview.

How??

Comment: Post some code where you are operating with navigation controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In second case your `UIScrollView` doesn't work because your `UIImageView` was added later.

You can try to add firstly as subview `UIImageView` and then add `UIScrollView` with clear background color.